# How to customize cron to run on pre-assigned time in laravel?

Tags: laravel

I have a table schedule : **`schedule_demo`**

```
id       name     schedule_date          tag            status
1       test_1    2023-01-28 09:16:12    test_1_sch       1
2       test_2    2023-01-28 11:30:30    test_2_sch       1
3       test_3    2023-01-28 14:50:20    test_3_sch       1
```

In **`Commands/ScheduleDemo.php`**

```
  protected $signature = 'run:scheduleDemo';
  public function handle()
    {
        $scheduleData = ScheduleDemo::where('status', '=', 1)
                 ->where('scheduleDate', '=', strtotime('now'))->get();
        if (count($scheduleData) > 0) {
            foreach ($scheduleData as $value) {
                $response = $this->client->request('POST', 'https://example.com', [
                 'headers' => [
                    'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                 ],
                 'form_params' => ['from' => $value->name, 'tag' => $value->tag]
               ]);
               $response = json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents());
               if ($response && $response['error'] == 0) {
                 $value->status = 2;
                 $value->save();
               } else {
                echo "\n FAILED \n\n";
             }
            }
        } else {
            echo "\n SCHEDULE IS EMPTY \n\n";
        }
    }
```

In **`Kernel.php`**

```
 protected $commands = [
        'App\Console\Commands\ScheduleDemo'
    ];
    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {        
        $schedule->command('run:scheduleDemo')
            ->everyFiveMinutes()
            ->withoutOverlapping()
            ->runInBackground();
    }
```

I run `crontab -e` and add : `* * * * * php /job/project/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1`

I created a cron in laravel, And got API calls five minutes each time.Like the part I did above, it was successful for this. Now I don't want to run every five minutes, but I want to time `scheduleDate = strtotime('now')` it will run cron.

***For example:*** `scheduleDate = 2023-01-28 09:16:12` = `strtotime('now')` it will run automatically, rather than assigning it a default of five minutes each time. I.e. `scheduleDate` time is equal to current time then it will automatically run cron. Is there any way to do that. I would like to hear everyone's opinion. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

How about use at or between?

```
$schedule->command('foo')
          ->at('13:00');


$schedule->command('foo')
          ->between('8:00', '17:00');
```